# How can I use variable outside the function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('#liveUpdate').click(


        $.getJSON("http://freegeoip.net/json/", function(data) {
            var country = data.country_name;
            var ip = data.ip;
        });

        alert(country);

    });
```

I wanted to use `country` outside `getJSON` but not the correct result. Tried to define variable top of the `click` function but not resolved my problem.

How can I fix it?

Comment: you can try `$('#liveUpdate').click(function() {
    var country = null;

    $.getJSON("http://freegeoip.net/json/", function(data) {
        country = data.country_name;
        var ip = data.ip;
    });

    alert(country);

});`

Comment: @Sushil: That won't work.  AJAX is *asynchronous*.

Comment: @Bergi - Heh, you got in right as I clicked close with that same target :)

Comment: you're right @RocketHazmat he can just use `$.ajax` with `async: false`

Comment: @Sushil: I would *not* suggest that, it's a bad practice.  It locks up the browser and doesn't teach you the correct way to use AJAX.

Comment: yeah that's true but if its not a heavy function, why not use it or he can go with @Ammar's approach

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change your approach to work with the asynchronous nature of ajax.

Say you wanted to use country in a function

```
function someFunction(country){
    //country used here
}
```

Then call it within the success callback of the ajax

```
$('#liveUpdate').click(function(){
        $.getJSON("http://freegeoip.net/json/", function(data) {
            country = data.country_name;
            var ip = data.ip;
            someFunction(country);
        });

    });
```